# Best way to declare a global variable from firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

i want to declare a global object from firebase:

My code looks like this:

app.component.ts

```
export class AthleticsApp {
af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            // here i want to make the user global somehow
        });
```

is it possible to make the user global? And whats the best or easiest way to do so?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Declare a variable outside the class ,i.e, before it like `var MyVariable = ' ';`

Comment: Sure, that will work for one class. But if i want to use that global in another class, it dont work anymore:

"Error in .... class TabsPage -  caused by: GLOBAL_USER is not defined"

Comment: Actually it is not for one class . That global variable is accessible by all the classes if you are writing at the top(lets assume). In that case, it will be available in all the scopes equally. Please try it once. I am putting that as an answer. If it helps you then please upvote / accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If all you really need to do is to supply a global object to your components, consider an [opaque token](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html).

However, as the object has to be resolved as well - and ideally only once - I'd consider embedding this in a small service acting as a facade to firebase:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private _user;
  public get user(): Observable<User> {
    if (!this._user) {
      this._user = this.af.auth.cache();  // .cache guarantees at most one request
    }
    return this._user;
  }

  private af;

  constructor() {
  ...establish af reference
  }
}
```

You make this service available to all components by adding it as a provider on the AppComponent level:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<my-comp></my-comp>'
  providers: [
    UserService
  ]
})
export class AppComponent { 
}
```

Components needing the user object can access it thru the service. Note, the user will be resolved **only once**, courtesy of .cache operator in service.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: '...'
})
export class MyComp { 

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.userService.user.subscribe(user => {
      ...deal with the user
    });
  }
}
```

If you really want to get rid of userService.user.subscribe (though it will return instantly for all subsequent requests), you could resolve the object ahead of first usage by using a [route resolver](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html)

Edit: It may need stressing that you are passing around the **same instance** of UserService in all components by adding it as a provider on AppComponent level - thus it acts as a globally available variable. This is a very powerful feature specific to [angular 2 dependency injection](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have 2 classes:

```
var MyVariable = ' ';
export class AthleticsApp1 {
af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            // MyVariable is accessible here
        });

export class AthleticsApp2 {
af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            // MyVariable is accessible here
        });
```

Now the *MyVariable* is accessible by the both the classes without any issue cause it is falling under the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Incase of firebase update your user object over time, I would suggest using Redux and put that user object inside the state tree.

This sulotion will result only one object that every other compoents will use concurrently and each component will get the most updated object from firebase.

Ngrx/Store (Redux for Angular2): https://github.com/ngrx/store

Then change:

```
af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            your_redux_store_object.dispach({action: Actions.USER_UPDATE,payload: user});
        });
```

Each compoenent will consume updates over time by the same store object.